# How can I add more than 3 stops for Tailwind gradient

Tags: tailwind-css

There are three gradient stops- **from-***, **via-*** and **to-*** are available as Tailwind utilities. I need 1 more gradient stop like **via2-*** which will support Tailwind's color and percentage. Is it a good idea when I need a gradient color with four stops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using a [custom background image](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#using-custom-values).

Via configuration:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: ({ theme }) => ({
        foo: `linear-gradient(${theme('colors.blue.500')},${theme('colors.green.500')},${theme('colors.red.500')},${theme('colors.yellow.500')})`,
      }),
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="bg-foo h-40 w-40">
```

Or as an arbitrary value class:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="bg-[linear-gradient(theme(colors.blue.500),theme(colors.green.500),theme(colors.red.500),theme(colors.yellow.500))] h-40 w-40">
```

Otherwise, you could look at [creating your own plugin that creates `via2-` dynamic class utilities](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#dynamic-utilities), though you would need to juggle the CSS variables that Tailwind uses internally to generate the gradient from the existing `from-`, `via-`, and `to-` classes.

Answer (score 0):

arbitrary value class:

```html
<div class="bg-[linear-gradient(266deg,rgba(175,170,195,1)0%,rgba(175,170,195,0)22%,rgba(175,170,195,0)78%,rgba(175,170,195,1)100%)]"></div>
```